# ConfigurationManager does not exist in current context in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Hi im following a video in youtube how to connect a connectionString and in his video he go like this

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["hotelConnection"].ToString();
```

and it goes perfectly fine to him. But when come to me it gives me an error that says "does not exist in the current context"
He is using VS 2010 whilst on me is VS2013.. I google down why is that and because it is the version. Any ideas how to resolve that part?

Comment: You're probably missing a "using" statement for System.Configuration.

Comment: Add `System.Configuration` assembly & `System.Configuration` namespace.

Comment: Nope. I have this using System.Data.SqlClient;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the references folder, check if you have `System.Configuration` assembly, if not add it using `add reference` option. After that include the following namespace at the top:-

```
using System.Configuration;
```

Answer (score 0):

check if you have System.Configuration assembly, if not add it

Try This in top of document (recommended )

```
using System.Configuration;
```

Else write in line as `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["hotelConnection"].ToString()`